# XML validation in .net core 2.2 and .net framework 4.6

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, xsd, schema

I am trying to convert our application from .net framework to .net core 2.2. We have a method that validates an XML against an XSD. It was working without any issue in .net framework but as I moved it to .net core, it throws this error. Looks like, It is unable to load the schema.

> System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: 'The 'EntityId'
>   element is not declared.'

It is throwing error on "schemas.Compile()".

```cs
string XsdFile = "MainSchema.xsd";
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add("", XsdFile);
schemas.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
schemas.Compile();
```

**MainSchema.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="Identity.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="CCIdentity">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="EntityId" />
        <xs:element ref="EntityType" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Identity.xsd:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="EntityType">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="2" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="EntityId">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1" />
        <xs:maxLength value="32" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764271/different-behavior-for-full-framework-and-net-core-for-xml-schema-compilation) of any use to you? it mentions `AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);`

Comment: Yeah I read that thread but I didn't understand that. What is AppContext ?

Comment: Google is great, have a read of [this MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.setswitch?view=netframework-4.8). Then, give it a try and see if it works for you. If it does, awesome! If not, try, try again.